# How big is the PostgreSQL footprint?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to calculate the footprint of a PostgreSQL database? I will have some tables with indexes, foreign keys and some join tables. I can calculate how many data I will store depending on the data types I use, but with what do I have to multiply it to get a rough idea of the total size of the database?

Comment: You can estimate a rough initial size, but It will change once you start using it. Anyway when you calculate it keep in mind that FK does not take space unless you deliberately create an index for it and you decide to create a data set with small amount of data and then multiply it, small amount of data should be more then thousand rows, otherwise estimations will be too large

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create schema populate data(at least with random data) and calculate

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg) pz , pg from pg_database_size('dbname') pg
```